# using gcloud storage on cloud run with ruby

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

Usually using the [google-cloud-storage](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/google-cloud-storage) gem to read/write files

This gem expects a .json service account key path, or an environment variable specifying the path

I was wondering how this could work in a cloudrun context, as the expected environment variable can't reference a static file path. A service account can be specified when deploying to cloudrun, but how to reach the service account info it with such tool ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While running on Cloud Run (or Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine, App Engine, Cloud Functions...), you don't need to specify any JSON key files (or the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable). All Google Cloud client libraries automatically get credentials (a token) from the compute platform your app is running on.

In fact this gem’s documentation linked to says:

> This library uses Service Account credentials to connect to Google Cloud services. **When running on Compute Engine the credentials will be discovered automatically**

So you should delete that field in the code, and it should be working on Cloud Run just fine.

---

You need to specify a key file path (or env. variable) if:

- you need want to use a different identity than the default/configured identity of the platform you're running on

  - (e.g. in this case service account you configured for the Cloud Run service)
- while running outside Google Cloud

Comment: Another reason you may need to specify a JSON key file is for google-cloud-storage functionality that requires full service account credentials. An example is generating signed URLs.

Comment: See this [google-cloud-storage issue comment](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/issues/3601#issuecomment-508791864) regarding token vs service account credentials.

Answer (score -1):

> This gem expects a .json service account key path, or an environment variable specifying the path
>
> I was wondering how this could work in a cloudrun context, as the expected environment variable can't reference a static file path.

The value of the `GOOGLE_CLOUD_CREDENTIALS` environment variable can be: "Path to JSON file, or **JSON contents**". So if you can't reference a static file path, provide the entire contents of your JSON key file as the value for the environment variable.

See [google-cloud-storage Authentication](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-storage/latest/file.AUTHENTICATION.html) for full docs.

Comment: Or specify the service account with --service-account option.